# Loading partial templates with AJAX/PJAX

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy

I am trying to load content using [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) (basically AJAX with history). So far I have managed to catch PJAX requests and load the correct content.

My problem is finding the correct template to use for each page. Currently I am using...

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
locate_template($post_type.'.php', true);
```

This sort of works but it's not perfect. For example it will never hit `front-page.php`. Is there a "right" way to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: I think that you should be using [`get_template_part()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_template_part/) instead of `locate_template()`

Comment: Really? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the performance I would recommend using the [WordPress API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) instead of trying to load markup using ajax.

If you look at **wp-includes/template-loader.php** you can see how WordPress itself figures out which template to use. You could in theory just load that file, but you might have problems with `template_redirect`.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

Alternatively, you can just copy paste the code you need.

```
$template = false;
if     ( is_embed()          && $template = get_embed_template()          ) :
elseif ( is_404()            && $template = get_404_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_search()         && $template = get_search_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_front_page()     && $template = get_front_page_template()     ) :
elseif ( is_home()           && $template = get_home_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_post_type_archive() && $template = get_post_type_archive_template() ) :
elseif ( is_tax()            && $template = get_taxonomy_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_attachment()     && $template = get_attachment_template()     ) :
  remove_filter('the_content', 'prepend_attachment');
elseif ( is_single()         && $template = get_single_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_page()           && $template = get_page_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_singular()       && $template = get_singular_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_category()       && $template = get_category_template()       ) :
elseif ( is_tag()            && $template = get_tag_template()            ) :
elseif ( is_author()         && $template = get_author_template()         ) :
elseif ( is_date()           && $template = get_date_template()           ) :
elseif ( is_archive()        && $template = get_archive_template()        ) :
else :
  $template = get_index_template();
endif;
/**
 * Filters the path of the current template before including it.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $template The path of the template to include.
 */
if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) ) {
  include( $template );
}
```

Comment: I've remade the site twice since I asked this question but it's a good answer!